# How do I handle @Produces exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

My `@Inject` may fail if my `@Produces` throws my unchecked exception `MyRuntimeException` which extends `RuntimeException`

I have a default exception handler that I'm trying to use:

```
@Provider
public class DefaultExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException ex) {

        return Response.serverError().entity(message).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

    }

}
```

The `DefaultExceptionMapper` is registered in my `ApplicationConfig`.

However it is not getting invoked when the `@Inject` `@Produces` throws `MyRuntimeException`.
My REST Interface is returning a not so nice error response.

```
[ERROR   ] CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getMyBean" on bean "BeanId(my-app.war#MyProcuderFactory, null)". Exception data: com.mycompany.ex.MyRuntimeException: 
    at com.mycompany.MyProcuderFactory.getMyBean(MyProcuderFactory.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5772)
    at [internal classes]
```

Comment: I am confused by "RuntimeException" and "MyRuntimeException". Shouldn't your mapper map "MyRuntimeException"?

Comment: You might have overlooked to make MyRuntimeEx extend RuntimeEx.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion works for application servers implementing Java EE6 specifications. I had similar problem trying to register a JSON Mapper provider. Thus I replaced ApplicationConfig with an empty one, which worked for me:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

I also admire your Response build which apparently follows best practices. Yet please find below another Response build which might be useful for debugging purposes:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).header("x-exception-detail", ex.getLocalizedMessage()).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

A CNTR0020E is thrown in case of a RuntimeException which has no @ApplicationException annotation. 
So you might either change your RuntimException to some checked Exception or annotate your RuntimeException